# In GTA V a "Mission disrupted" error appears and can't start the mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA V, everytime I go to the northeast FIB mission "Monkey Business", that has a small pier, an in-game message appears saying "Mission disrupted" and doesn't allow to start the mission.

I've tried going by land and sea and this message appears both times.

Answer (score 7):

Searched online and the solution that worked for me was to get a taxi.

Went to the airport (Yeah, on the other side of the island, but always has taxis), and used a taxi to go to the mission spot. There is a hotkey to skip the ride.

Comment: This worked for me. Although afterwards I realised I could have called a taxi from the phone, instead of going all the way to the airport

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, and I managed to solve it by driving around in the vicinity of the farm until the mission marker reappears, then trying again.

Comment: Yup, I can confirm this works. Just drive around and come back

Answer (score 1):

You must drive the proper dirt path there. I always tried to take a shortcut which doesn’t work.

I also drove around a bit until the blip reappeared to maybe beforehand so maybe this works as well.

Answer (score 1):

The way I’ve always done it is drive as close as I can without disrupting, go off to the left side towards the trees and walk from there. The mission doesn’t disrupt that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I could only get it to work by hopping in the taxi as Michael and skipping the journey.

Having other characters drive there, or having a normal or hurried taxi didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this bug and tried to use the taxi to reach the location. The same bug popped up. I walked away from the location and waited for the marker to appear again. I walked back as close as possible to the shoreline and it finally allowed me to start the mission.

Comment: Did you skip the ride when you used the taxi? AFAIK, it will only work if you skip the ride. Doing so resets the affected area.

Comment: Ooohh. I didn’t know skipping the ride was the key. I let the drive play out. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I just kept switching characters and driving there. All 3 need to get there anyways, Franklin's already near for the final switch. Just drove up, mission commenced.

Answer (score 0):

The mission "Monkey Business" starts by stopping the car on the dirt track before the icon disappears. Then, get out of your car and walk to the icon. This should start the mission.

Answer (score -1):

Play as Franklin and just try to wait until around 17.30 (you can check the time in the pause menu or on your phone) then take a cab to the mission and you'll meet Michael who's looking towards the water.